# VBA nested loop - outer loop doesnt jump to next value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, lookup

I'm trying to do a macro to produce a list based on a lookup list. For some reason the outer loop doesnt work, it only iterates once.

```
Sub Macro5()

Dim LookupRng As Range
Dim Store As String
Dim jrow As Integer
Dim irow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Set LookupRng = Sheet1.Range("B2") ' The Lookup range
jrow = Sheet2.Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' last row of list of values to be searched
irow = Sheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' last row of lookup range


Sheet3.Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).Clear

For j = 2 To jrow
Store = Sheet2.Cells(j, 20).Value ' the value to be searched in the lookup range

For i = 1 To irow
If LookupRng.Value = Store Then
Sheet3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = LookupRng.Offset(0, -1).Value
End If
Set LookupRng = LookupRng.Offset(1, 0)
Next i
Next j
```

The i loop works, it searches all values that match "Store", but for some reason the j loop doesnt seem to be working, it doesnt jump to the next value of the "Store" list.
I'm new to this so would prefer a simple solution, but any help will be very appreciated

Comment: Have you checked the value of `jrow`? Have you used the debugger to step thru you code?

Comment: Should `LookupRng` go back to B2 each time?

Comment: If you use `Find` method you can avoid the loop altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Loops with Offset

- The issue was that you are not resetting the `Lookup Range` to the initial position after each inner loop finishes. So the following loops were trying to compare the values below the `Lookup Range` which were empty.
- You should abandon the idea of 'offsetting' and use `Cells` or `Range` and increase the rows or define the range and use a `For Each` loop. But the best would be to use only one loop and use `Application.Match` to find a match.

**A Quick Fix**

```
Option Explicit

Sub lookupLoop()

    Dim ilCell As Range ' Initial Lookup Cell Range
    Dim lCell As Range ' Lookup Cell Range
    Dim dCell As Range ' Destination Cell Range
    Dim Store As Variant ' Current Value in Search Range
    Dim iRow As Long ' Last Row of Lookup Range
    Dim jRow As Long ' Last Row of Search Range
    Dim i As Long ' Lookup Range Rows Counter
    Dim j As Long ' Search Range Rows Counter
    
    Set ilCell = Sheet1.Range("B2")
    iRow = Sheet1.Range("B" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    jRow = Sheet2.Range("T" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Sheet3.Range("A2:A" & Sheet3.Rows.Count).Clear
    Set dCell = Sheet3.Range("A2")
    
    For j = 2 To jRow
        Store = Sheet2.Cells(j, "T").Value
        Set lCell = ilCell '***
        For i = 2 To iRow
            If lCell.Value = Store Then
                dCell.Value = lCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
                Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
                Exit For
            End If
            Set lCell = lCell.Offset(1)
        Next i
    Next j

End Sub
```

An `Application.Match` solution might look like this:

```
Sub lookupAM()

    Dim lrg As Range ' Lookup Range (Read)
    Dim vrg As Range ' Values Range (Write)
    Dim srg As Range ' Search Range
    Dim sCell As Range ' Current Cell in Search Range
    Dim dCell As Range ' Current Cell in Destination Range
    Dim cMatch As Variant ' Current Match
    Dim lRow As Long ' Last Row of Lookup Range
    Dim sRow As Long ' Last Row of Search Range
    
    lRow = Sheet1.Range("B" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set lrg = Sheet1.Range("B2:B" & lRow)
    Set vrg = lrg.Offset(, -1)
    
    sRow = Sheet2.Range("T" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set srg = Sheet2.Range("T2:T" & sRow)
    
    Sheet3.Range("A2:A" & Sheet3.Rows.Count).Clear
    Set dCell = Sheet3.Range("A2")
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        cMatch = Application.Match(sCell.Value, lrg, 0)
        If IsNumeric(cMatch) Then
            dCell.Value = vrg.Cells(cMatch).Value
        End If
        Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
    Next sCell

End Sub
```

Comment: you're a legend

Comment: hi @VBasic2008, would you know if the application.match solution would work if my lookup list has more than one right side entry for each left side value? Thanks again